# Cannot remove "empty directories" from my external hard drive after rsync fail

Tags: directory, ntfs, rsync, rm

It seems like I have 4 empty directories on my external hard drive (NTFS). But I can't remove them with nautilus or a terminal.

I think this happened just after my attempt to synchronize 2 directories from 2 different external hard drives plugged to my computer using `rsync` with the options `-trlD` with root privileges. During processing, the destination drive may has been unplugged and I interrupted `rsync` at least one time.

Now, in the destination directory, I have 4 "empty directories" `1_archi.txt`, `2_services.txt`, `3_IPv6.txt` and `notes_arp.pdf`. When I try to look inside with nautilus, It opens a new window at `.`, the current directory. They were supposed to be text and pdf files as suggested by their extensions. The source directory seems fine.

```bsh
$ ls -ila -1b *
1_archi.txt:
total 4
18180 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem    0 nov.  29  2019 .
  502 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem 4096 juil.  5 23:13 ..

2_services.txt:
total 8
18181 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem    0 nov.  29  2019 .
  502 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem 4096 juil.  5 23:13 ..
 1483 -rwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem  588 nov.  29  2019 a0eafdb6c612001a1b29f853269dd3f9

3_IPv6.txt:
total 4
18182 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem    0 nov.  29  2019 .
  502 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem 4096 juil.  5 23:13 ..

notes_arp.pdf:
total 5
18183 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem    0 nov.  29  2019 .
  502 drwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem 4096 juil.  5 23:13 ..
 1862 -rwxrwxrwx 1 zatigem zatigem  362 nov.  29  2019 60d11afaba12001a1b29f853269dd3f9
```

Obviously, I tried `rm` and I even tried to [remove from the index](https://serverfault.com/a/565915) :

```bsh
$ sudo rm -r 1_archi.txt
rm: cannot remove '1_archi.txt': No such file or directory

$ sudo find . -inum 18180 -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./1_archi.txt’: No such file or directory
```

I can go inside using `cd` and even create a file within. But I just can't remove the directory... I can remove the weird files `a0eaf...` and `60d11...` but it doesn't change anything. I tried `ntfsfix` as well. I tried to empty every trash I could find on my computer and external hard drive. Finally, I tried to directly delete them with Windows' file explorer but the following error occured:

```
Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

Comment: Run a `chkdsk` from a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ravexina suggested, I ran a command prompt as administrator from a Windows machine and I inserted the following lines, as my external hard drive was at `D:`:

```
C:\> D:
D:\> chkdsk /f
```

Then it found the broken indexes, the "empty directories", and deleted them.

**Warning:** This can result in data loss. For example, if one of your file doesn't respect the [Windows' naming conventions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) (it contains a '?'…) then it will probably be erased !

**Note:** If you don’t have a Windows machine, you can also try `ntfsfix` or backup your data and reformat the partition on which the problem occurs.